# Методы хранения огромных массивов данных

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Приветствую великие умы stackoverflow. Недавно устроился на новую работу, где разрабатывается огромный проект. Вот действительно огромный. А на огромный проект, конечно приходится огромный объём данных. Давайте по порядку.

Тонкости проекта не могу поведать ибо какая-то тайна компании, но попробую описать обособлено.

#### Суть вопроса

Есть, условно говоря, площадки, которые скупаются, выставляются на торги и перепродаются. К этим площадкам привязаны фотоотчёты с множеством фотографий с разными типами. Так же к этим площадкам привязаны события. Продажа, покупка, обустройство, дата строительства и всё в таком духе. Кроме всего прочего к этим же площадкам привязаны ещё некоторые элементы. И вроде бы пока структура базы данных лаконична, до одного момента.

Площадки привязаны к определённому пользователю, условно говоря, а пользователей может быть сотни. Без преувеличений. И такая проблема, что площадки могут пересекаться. Разные пользователи могут владеть одной и той же площадкой.

В текущей ситуации под каждого такого пользователя создаются таблицы в базе данных, сколько точно не скажу, но больше десяти точно. Где хранятся площадки, фотографии, события и всё остальное, что привязано к площадке. Мне кажется, такой подход не совсем верный. Нагромождения таблиц и последующие изменения вызывают сложности, как мне кажется.

1-ый вопрос. Такой подход именно на данный проект уместен или это как была дич, так и осталась?

2-ой вопрос. Я хочу предложить изменить структуру (благо они сами хотят найти оптимальные решения). Что-то вроде создать таблицу пользователей, таблицу площадок и собственно связать каждого пользователя с отдельными площадками. Тогда возникает вопрос, случится ли беда с ID ибо чувствую там может дойти и до триллиардов. Стоит ли такая идея жизни?

3-ий вопрос. Сталкивались ли вы с подобными огромными проектами и какие решения видели вы.

Лично для меня это первый проект таких масштабов.

Comment: Под ID используйте bigint, его должно хватить. Вам там ниже правильно советуют - берите другую БД (если возможно), с MySQL масса проблем. Особенно когда начнет не хватать одного сервера и понадобиться репликация. Она у MySQL конечно есть ... Но вот позавчера у нас некорректно завершился один сервер (на MySQL) ... состояние репликации слетело, базы разошлись. Сверить 200 млн строк задача та еще ...

Comment: И да, таблицы должны создаваться при разработке приложения, в процессе работы они создаваться не должны. Так что все объекты в одной таблице, с id пользователя. Или связка объект-пользователь в отдельной таблице, если объект действительно один и тот же, со всеми атрибутами, а управляющих несколько. И фотографии я бы хранил не в БД, а в БД только пути к ним и возможно md5, что бы одинаковые фото 10 раз не хранить

Comment: Сами по себе фотографии хранятся на сервере, а в базе хранится путь до них, конечно. О репликации речи пока и не заходит. Спасибо за ответы, кстати :3

Comment: в чем огромность проекта, таки не раскрыто. "сотни пользователей" - это значит 200 пользователей... сколько площадок - не озвучено. ну тогда включаю режим ВАНГА. ок, площадок всего 124. и всё??!!))

Answer (score 1):

1. Подход не верный, правильно: новый пользователь = новая запись в таблице пользователей
2. Используйте 'мощные' СУБД Oracle, Postgres и др. дабы иметь меньше проблем с большими данными. А триллиард записей, это можно хранить (к примеру максимальное значение PKey в PSQL 9223372036854775807), но использовть будет сложновато ввиду снижения производительности
3. Сталкивался, решение описал выше ;)
   Удачи!

Comment: При такой системе как упростить поиск информации? То есть чтобы сервер не слёг в поисках конструкций и информации по конструкции (фотографий, событий и всего прочего)?

Comment: Я пока вижу только что-то типа хранения временной информации в таблицах, по типу хранения ID конструкций и связанных с ними элементов, чтобы не искать всё это раз за разом в базе данных. Но смутно пока представляю как это будет работать ибо никогда, повторюсь, не сталкивался с таким огромным объёмом данных.

Comment: @ПавелБаранов При выборке большого количества объектов конечно каждый join это серьезное снижение производительности. Обычно решается хранением уже собранной по всем таблицам информации к конкретному объекту. Т.е. приходиться дублировать информацию и еще ее как то синхронизировать, например триггерами. Так же можно рассмотреть хранение нужной суммарной информации в кеше, например в Redis